# Can i control the brakes of a car by the OBD II Interface?

Tags: brakes, obd-ii

I'm doing a senior project about automating the braking system in cars and make it smarter

Comment: So what have you researched so far? Which car?

Comment: It would depend on the car and the age of the car. The number of parameters accessed by the OBD II interface between older cars and newer cars, and even then it varies on the "level" of car. So a Mercedes Benz from 1999 will have more parameters accessible via the OBD II than a 2017 Toyota Aygo would for example.

Comment: FYI Only some vehicles with active traction control systems will even have a mechanism for the computer to *apply* the brakes.

Comment: Not thru OBD but you could trick the ABS system by sending false signals to the rotation sensors, I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for.  I'm assuming this is either an automated car control or hacking project.

Comment: @Chris you can definitely actuate the valves in the bpmv abs assembly through the dlc. Why trick the sensors when the functionality is built into the ebcm?

Comment: This cannot be achieved using OBDII. However using CAN bus it is doable in some cars.

Answer (score 4):

OBD stands for [On Board Diagnostics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics). It is used to **provide** vehicle diagnostic information. It is read-only, except for specific log entries and specific fault codes that can be reset.
So no, you cannot control the braking system of a car through the OBD port.

That does not however mean that a vehicle cannot [be hacked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/On-board_diagnostics#Security_issues) through its diagnostic interface, but this is heavily dependent on car make/model and is not legal in any way.

Comment: It might be perfectly legal depending on where you are @MadMarky, but you are correct it's good to be prudent.

Comment: On some cars you can force the ABS to operate to bleed the system...

Comment: @SolarMike, that's true, but then you'd most likely be accessing the proprietary CAN Bus or similar, not strictly using the OBDII interface.